# What is the meaning of : ballDX = math.random(2) == 1 and 100 or -100

Tags: lua, love2d

I am learning about how to make a pong game with CS50 game dev course. But i don't know whats the meaning of

```
ballDX = math.random(2) == 1 and 100 or -100
```

Comment: https://nachtimwald.com/2019/02/20/lua-ternary/

Comment: You'll get either 100 or -100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means, that ballDX will get only two random values: 100 or -100.

- If `math.random(2)` returns 2, then statement `2 == 1 and 100` will
  be false, ballDX gets value `false or -100`, it means -100.
- if `math.random(2)` returns 1, then statement `1 == 1 and 100` will
  be true, ballDX gets value `100 or -100`, it means it gets first
  true variable, it means 100.